# How to simulate postgresql recovery mode?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-8.3

I would like to simulate putting postgresql into "recovery mode".
Few times i have situation where postgresql puted himself into recovery mode. In logs i had:

Oct 18 06:37:35 xx postgres[5738]: [19-1] 2014-10-18 06:37:35.441 CEST|5738|xx|yy|FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode

It was caused by oom which killed one of process.
But when i try to simulate it in test environment - postgresql restarts.

How to prevent postgresql from restart and let him stay in recovery mode?

Comment: Didn't notice you were on *8.3*. That's super-obsolete. Plan an upgrade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to force PostgreSQL into recovery, you can create a `recovery.conf` with no `restore_command` or streaming replication configuration set. Leave `hot_standby` set to `off` in `postgresql.conf`.

Personally I recommend taking a base backup (`pg_basebackup -X stream`) and using that, rather than doing it to the original DB.

Comment: I've postgresql 8.3, and i haven't pg_basebackup. I created empty restore.conf and restarted postgresql, but without effect.

Comment: @undefine Er... `recovery.conf`. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/recovery-config.html . But you're on an *incredibly ancient* version, so this advice probably doesn't apply.

Comment: @undefine In 8.3 the docs are http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/continuous-archiving.html , there's no separate page for recovery.conf . (Prior link was intentionally to /9.1/ not /current/ as that's the oldest version that had the page)

Answer (score 1):

You can put the database into recovery mode by forcing an unclean shutdown of any of the backend processes, other than the postmaster itself.  For example, with `kill -9`.

Yes, PostgreSQL restarts.  That is why it going into recovery mode.  Recovery mode is a part of starting up again after an unclean shutdown.  If the database was idle when it crashed, then the recovery mode might only last a fraction of a second before the database reopens for business, so you might not observe it passing through this mode.

Comment: I asked this question because production database on postgresql 8.3 puted himself into recovery mode, but - didn't restarts after this. I would like to simulate this behaviour and impact of database in this mode to other elements of infrastructure. So - question is - how to put db into recovery mode and prevent from restart? :)

Comment: What did the server log file say?  If it encountered an issue that prevented it from restarting, the log file should say what the issue was.